# Getting invalid_request when IsAuthorizationValid returns false

Tags: dotnetopenauth

Whenever my IsAuthorizationValid method in my IAuthorizationServer implementation returns false, AuthorizationServer.HandleTokenRequest gives me an invalid_request response. I was expecting something like invalid_scope or authorization_expired.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth 2 error codes aren't correctly implemented in DotNetOpenAuth v4.0.x.  v4.1 improves it significantly but hasn't been released yet.